# WCF Web service - which is best basicHttpBinding or netTcpBinding

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have gone through several articles, but i want to know the best suited Binding for my project.

I have 3 Bulk Sms servers that send sms to customers, As :

1. I have designed a windows form application in which clients enter the mobile numbers and sms text.
2. Application connects to WCF Service and request is sent to the Bulk Sms server based on Language selected by clients.

I want to know which is best for my project, **basicHttpBinding or netTcpBinding** ? I am more concern about the security.

How to secure my WCF service with login ID and password. Since there are many clients running my Windows Form Application, and i want to provide a UserId and Password to them, so that no other can use my WCF servcie or misuse my Winform Application ?

Answer (score 0):

The both have their use cases:
netTcpBinding is use if you are running within a farewall that is within an intranet.This takes advantage of tcp and give faster speed.

basicHttpBinding is use when want to provide rest like service so that http enable clients like mobile phones,tv and other can access your service.it has lesser speed but greater reach

Comment: i want a security mechanism to protect WCF service from misuse. And this WCF service is hosted in shared server. so i cannot install certificate.